# Q&A Page about Exploit-development

Tags: support, scope

i was asking myself if some Information Security Page is not to general for asking questions about exploit development. So what could i do or someone else to establish/build a Stackexchange Q&A Page explicit for Exploit development? Kind regards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To some extent, exploit development is covered here. However, sometimes the question steps too much into the coding techniques used that it becomes a better fit for Stackoverflow.

To be honest, I agree with you. I don't think it's unreasonable to have an SE Q&A site for exploit development. To start such site, you can go ahead and [create a proposal on Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=technology). Explain the reasons behind your proposal and add whatever information you think is relevant.

Then try to promote your proposal. If enough people join it, SE will give you a private beta. If things go well, you'll go a public beta. If things go even better, you'll have a full SE site for that topic.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the advice :)